# Do I have to use “about” in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar

Do I have to use “about” just like number2?

1. The book *you told me* sold out in one day.
2. The book *you told me about* sold out in one day.

[ *You told me* the story. ] -> [ The story *you told me* was great. ]

Can't I make the sentence like this without 'about'?

Comment: Welcome to the community!  I hope you enjoy participating and find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

Most verbs can be directly associated with a maximum two things (nouns, pronouns, or whatever) - a subject, and (optionally) an object. If you want to associate any other things to the verb, you have to use a preposition to define the relationship between the thing and the verb.

> You told me **about** the book

In this sentence, **you** is the subject and **me** is the object of the verb. In order associate the book with the verb, you need to use the preposition **about**.

When you want to make **book** the subject of another sentence, and use a relative clause to specify which book we are talking about:

> The book [that you told me about] sold out in one day.

you still need to use the preposition **about** in the relative clause, to describe the relationship between the book and the verb of the relative clause **told**

Comment: @JavaLatte - That's an excellent answer!

Comment: @rainsky - Your thank-you comments will always be appreciated!  It's also good practice in this community to upvote all the answers that were useful to you, and also to "accept" the best one (e.g. this very good one from JavaLatte).  That's the best way to show your appreciation. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do need to use "about" in the phrase "The book you told me about has sold out".  The first option - "The book you told me has sold out" is not correct.

There are other variants of this sentence that don't use "about".  Some examples are as follows.

- The book you **mentioned** sold out.
- The book you **mentioned to me** sold out.
- The book you **referred me to** sold out.
- The book you **encouraged me to read** sold out.

Comment: [ Tell me the story. ] -> [ The story you told me was great. ] Is this kind of sentence grammatically wrong?

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation.

Comment: @rainsky - I'm glad you value my explanation!

Comment: @rainsky - Re your second question, there is nothing grammatically wrong with the sentence "The story you told me was great."  You would **not** add "about"; your friend is not telling you "about" a story, he is just telling you a story.

Comment: @rainsky - Adding to my comment above, in many other cases, the "about" **will** be necessary - e.g. "the report you told me about was interesting", or "the candidate you told me about was very clever", or "the book you told me about was very enjoyable".  For an explanation of why this is the case, refer to the answer below by JavaLatte.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. You need "about" in the sentence.

> The book you told me about sold out in a day.

You could use other constructions instead:

> The book you told me to bring home sold out in a day.

Or

> The book you told me to read sold out in a day.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation.